# MySQL Return Type Variance - NULL, EMPTY, FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Why does `MySQL -> PHP` via `PDO` sometimes either return `NULL`, `EMPTY` (array), or `FALSE` when a `SELECT` query (and possibly other types) returns a zero-result set?

I can't quite seem to figure out in which cases each different type is returned... and I hope its not written somewhere on the front cover of the manual;  although I did look a bit.

EDIT 1:

So it seems this is a PDO thing, not MySQL.  PDO->FetchAll() will return an empty array if the result-set is zero, and FALSE on error.  What about `NULL`?   **And NO the column values I am requesting are not NULL in case that silly thought came to your head.**

Comment: "`EMPTY`" is not a thing that MySQL can return.

Comment: sorry, an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In detail it is important which function you are using.

In generally, "FALSE" means that some error occured.

Check out [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more details.

Comment: I'm really looking for something definitive. But thank you, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: What exact function are you talking about? Because I never got "NULL" in this context...

Comment: Let's just stick with SELECT. Any reason it would return null instead of empty, or vice versa?

Comment: I assume you're using the function "mysql_query" and the parameter is a String specifying a SELECT-Query. Then no, there is no way that it returns "NULL", because it either returns FALSE (Error in your query) or it returns a resource that is your result set (see the link in my answer for returned values).

Comment: In the question I state "via PDO"

Comment: Furthermore, I'm using a $statement->fetchAll(). PDO also returns a 'statement object' resource. When I fetchAll() on the statement object the results are sometimes null or an empty array. I'm  beginning to believe FALSE is returned on an error, however, most of the time I get no indication of an error unless I specifically print it out.

Comment: Okay, sorry, never used this. But [here](http://de1.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) you might find what you need. If there might be "NULL" returned, they'll tell you, in which case.